# Having trouble understanding this proof of König's theorem...

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

[image]

**What I understand**

I understand how they're picking U. I understand that M is a maximal matching so that if the minimum cover cover all edges in G, then it must necessarily cover all edges in M because M is a subset of E.

I understand that the size of the minimum cover can't be less than the size of M because it takes atleast |M| vertices to cover |M| edges where none of the vertices is incident with more than one edge.

Ok. So I think the idea of the proof is to show that if any neighboring vertices, a and b (elements of E), are in U (a set that covers M), then we can say that U covers E. And since U has a size of |M| (a size that it can't be less than), then this is the minimum cover. Is that right?

**What I don't understand**

The proof loses me when it introduces a' and b'. I don't understand how they fit into this proof.

Would appreciate some help.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$M$ is a maximal matching, and we’re assuming that $ab\notin M$. There must be either an edge in $M$ incident at $a$ or an edge in $M$ incident at $b$, because if not, we could add the edge $ab$ to $M$ to get a strictly bigger matching. Thus, either $a$ is matched (but not with $b$), and there is a $b'\ne b$ such that $ab'\in M$; or $a$ is not matched, and there is an $a'\ne a$ such that $a'b\in M$.

Suppose that $a$ is not matched, so that there is an $a'\ne a$ such that $a'b\in M$. Then $ab$ is an alternating path: it starts in $A$ at the unmatched vertex $a$, its first edge is not in $M$, and we don’t have to worry about later edges because there aren’t any. The edge $a'b\in M$ has one of its ends in $U$: since the end $b$ is the end of an alternating path, it’s the end of $a'b$ that we put into $U$. Thus, $b\in U$, and we’re done: $U$ covers the edge $ab$.

Thus, we may assume that there is a $b'\ne b$ such that $ab'\in M$. If $a\in U$, we’re done: once again $U$ covers the edge $ab$. Assume, then, that $a\notin U$. Then $b'$ must have been the end of $ab'$ chosen to go into $U$, so there must be an alternating path $P$ ending at $b'$. If vertex $b$ is in the path $P$, we can cut $P$ short at $b$ to get an alternating path $P'$ (that Diestel denotes by $Pb$) ending at $b$. If $b$ is not in $P$, we can extend $P$ by adding the edges $b'a$ and $ab$ to get again an alternating path $P'$ (that Diestel denotes by $Pb'a'b$) ending at $b$. Thus, in all cases there is an alternating path ending at $b$. If $b$ were unmatched by $M$, $P'$ would be an augmenting path, and we could extend $M$ to a larger matching. $M$, however, is maximal, so this is impossible, and $P'$ therefore cannot be an augmenting path. This in turn means that $b$ cannot be unmatched: it must be one end of some edge $e$ in $M$. And since it’s also an end of an alternating path, it must have been the end of $e$ that was put into $U$. Thus, $b\in U$, and yet again we find that $U$ covers the edge $ab$.

And $ab$ was arbitrary, so every edge of the graph has at least one of its ends in $U$, meaning that $U$ is a vertex cover of the edges. Finally, we put one vertex into $U$ for each edge of $M$, so $|U|=|M|$, as desired.

Comment: Thank You. It was a big help.

Comment: @The_Questioner: You’re welcome.

Comment: The second sentence in para 2 (Then ab is an alternating path...) is untrue (an alternating path must start from an unmatched vertex).

It should probably read like... Suppose there is no $b' \ne b$ s.t. $ab' \in M$. Then there must be an $a'$ s.t. $a'b \in M$. Because $a$ is unmatched and $ab$ is not in $M$, $ab$ is an alternating path, so $b \in U$.

Comment: Sorry; I mean to say... the second sentence in para 2 (Then $ab$ is an alternating path...) does not follow from the first sentence: an alternating path must start from an unmatched vertex, and $a'b \in M$ does not imply that $a$ is unmatched.

Comment: @lijie I agree with you. This proof seems to cover the cases of 1. $\exists b' \neq b$ such that $ab' \in M$ and 2. $\exists a' \neq a$ such that $a'b \in M$ but shouldn't there be a third case of $\exists a' \neq a$ such that $a'b \in M$ AND $\exists b' \neq b$ such that $ab' \in M$?

Comment: @NoppaweeApichonpongpan: I’ve slightly revised the first two paragraphs for greater clarity.